# show on slide in an overflow:hidden div

Tags: jquery, overflow, slide

I am to my knowledge on a tricky situation.
I have a div that is 200px high(overflow:hidden) and a child div that is 600px high.
I am sliding left and right the child div. The problem is that the child div gets cut of because of the overflow:hidden.

```
jQuery( '.haschild .hikashop_category_name a' ).click({slide: false}, function( e ) {     
    var slidecontent = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.hikashop_category_list');
    e.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('shown')) {
    jQuery( slidecontent ).animate({ 'right': '-100%'}, 400);
    jQuery(this).removeClass('shown');
}else{
    jQuery( slidecontent ).animate({ 'right': '0'}, 400);
    jQuery(this).addClass('shown');
}
```

Not quite sure what to do.

I know I could addClass to the parent and override the overflow. But then is a big jump when the child div appears.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I am sliding the child div to reveal its content. But the parent div is smaller than the child. I am trying to slide the child left and right to reveals its content when you click on the parent div. Does that make sense or just confused you more?cheers

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of what you are trying to do, may be it gets more clear from there.

Comment: this is what I am trying to do http://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range please hover building & hardware for example. the problem is that I have too many subcategories

Comment: You are trying to show an landscape bigger than your window. I can suggest you to make your window bigger or your landscape smaller, anyway, there's no SOLUTION for that... Just opinions...

Comment: I guess you are right. I tried changing the parent to display:block when the animation was completed but it jumped as well. I will just not have sub categories. cheers